# what are the downsides of using Hive LLAP(Tez) for ETL instead of traditional Hive(Tez) or Spark?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, bigdata, etl

Am trying to make my existing Hive queries to run faster. I ran few SELECT statements using Hive LLAP and found that its much faster ( 75% in my case ). So I took a bunch of my existing ETL workflows and ran them on Hive LLAP and it inserted records much faster as well. So is there any downside if I migrate my entire process to run on Hive LLAP in Production ?

Thanks in advance.
Jerryp